# Linux IMA - Why are there different hashes for system binaries in the ima log?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, integrity

I activated IMA for the first time, I have no previous experience with it.
In VirtualBox I have a fresh Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic), and modified `/etc/default/grub` as follows to activate `tcb` mode of IMA:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ima=on ima_policy=tcb"
```

After rebooting I inspected the file `/sys/kernel/security/ima/ascii_runtime_measurements` and saw that there are duplicates of system shared libraries (libc.so.6) and binaries. To create the list of duplicate entries for binaries in `/usr/bin` I used the following command:

```
</sys/kernel/security/ima/ascii_runtime_measurements grep '/usr/bin' | sort -k5 | uniq -d -D -f4
```

And this is the list I got (there are quite a lot more when instead grepping `'/usr/lib'`, but the gist is the same):

```
10 73a4e06c2fd8712321bc081ce3a75a5ba8ef1493 ima-ng sha1:0dbf371457aec429899b59452b0abfbfc80ef7e3 /usr/bin/bash
10 930b0510b096198a1dea1c93cd453792619f3af7 ima-ng sha1:6b6843dae13e009a3267eed8f472bebe47e39e31 /usr/bin/bash
10 20c4d71ec289096393c2c923a16af80278b36a62 ima-ng sha1:7fb7026bc4c60c743055f51924793d7b2a8b7076 /usr/bin/cat
10 e7854bea304dc1fa51d9378c9551d37ffe9ed5d1 ima-ng sha1:f2e2c1b280ae3268c15fd31cd8d2fcec9a984c5f /usr/bin/cat
10 67102b007f9728bd22de3cc23a98d064dc987d27 ima-ng sha1:6b12a8618bad94d1a867271c56e415dafc8a39c4 /usr/bin/chgrp
10 ebe285835bb49218f73ed83f26e38cef6d85a7b1 ima-ng sha1:56c77fecf65426a6426e75dee773d274aa9a0e75 /usr/bin/chgrp
10 33c21ccf701f108707f3611b50425b93e2c6dd53 ima-ng sha1:ad0c4616a7924d30eb47bd269263ecd1b15c9dd4 /usr/bin/chmod
10 defce3b02b70bf106b50b83130212538c7dc0960 ima-ng sha1:a2c9093d43118d3a60df0055953403a9424a0494 /usr/bin/chmod
10 58b3c2d312c090ecc0e0fbe265f6542105c834c1 ima-ng sha1:be4b48ca1926124109cb6e4d64f47f9dd06d0e00 /usr/bin/chown
10 7321f4e8addb8daf395c8964f1d8e3ec440451a1 ima-ng sha1:dfc1fdad63b534cd19c5d1d57624dd28350eb7a5 /usr/bin/chown
10 2af01a6e4c5644080b376598810689de8a6e5b88 ima-ng sha1:3c428338cfb2372fed664c8643860180592d2129 /usr/bin/cut
10 5a5d20c86ea3f9aa06de94471e59390a4876e7d7 ima-ng sha1:5b5f6692c272bf45f4ef53d852a660eb61cbaf69 /usr/bin/cut
10 042c9ed10b091c35a5e75aa3350ef4583e942c6e ima-ng sha1:42e94914c7800c7063c51d7a17aec3a2069a3769 /usr/bin/dash
10 df862ad372149f56a1760d0e9c427123ab04d5bb ima-ng sha1:585bf8f9c4632f164639ba3418b073dd4434f11a /usr/bin/dash
10 41980244f9ec54da397fea7f7be67d5b5471ff29 ima-ng sha1:a48601e25c1d7caf17c6076b488dd783b79d6b88 /usr/bin/date
10 68d01b6579429f0e265af588be2b96a749889532 ima-ng sha1:5383dc9a156c1fa161a62858919b9e4d87ff8356 /usr/bin/date
10 b20d60c235a33ddc082e74afdf411d94e80f14e7 ima-ng sha1:894cfafe216d3484b369594bccce7d263998828f /usr/bin/env
10 f3ac171447616f3a92ba5de232f240a5dcf9f11c ima-ng sha1:86bbfe9db3a4a61b4609eb49c9f6dd021e4b092e /usr/bin/env
10 1716c80c40c16f80146e89d11937cb2ed0e8c1b3 ima-ng sha1:4364e3437c75199361968b77f556d29c097b93e5 /usr/bin/grep
10 cc1e9e8e299bdd15d92e1be941220a8bf1c81dd6 ima-ng sha1:7407d340c9134738e04313fa0d247bc6ccf7a5aa /usr/bin/grep
10 126030ccf4025e485a54cb25da848f68bc77ce72 ima-ng sha1:4b8ba2b0e5ec8dae0203208f610e07e35f9b6ff9 /usr/bin/ln
10 d9763432b59125f591c5820a6e1758dd5a1e8c9a ima-ng sha1:99ba49bf0dbc39c2394e2d8e99f5dbfb983580aa /usr/bin/ln
10 0bc25f195edd73b44c83d4c71c3bed5fe19aa3ed ima-ng sha1:f4b3255233eda80c9d33c619b48cc8ac8aa37e1b /usr/bin/mkdir
10 77d71681fa537265817fac2d00510f5065955f4f ima-ng sha1:20c32e25f5bf1b189fa917b84e258a1cdfb66bad /usr/bin/mkdir
10 a1abbc414e5e184a3444b7edaa473c3de7ac5b8b ima-ng sha1:6512153a4f7d0bd15122626d17ed1083404004ff /usr/bin/perl
10 d5b0a6d649406b34ca51ce2164594372107ae007 ima-ng sha1:fa91ad099b3cee69d5a99d6cecd5e44b363d2385 /usr/bin/perl
10 a8fcea85c4cc0bc0efbe2e00fd3727ba25b5fda9 ima-ng sha1:99fb90d8f6bee2ff00996ee0ffe125f9e7623534 /usr/bin/rm
10 f446b3b081d36cdb26128c3ff9f507e2bb22ef48 ima-ng sha1:c139ccfd3cc261d1bc9218725a788949792bd6f2 /usr/bin/rm
10 481620d178417c35bbc9c507402fdde0e3d2267f ima-ng sha1:3c085e12539181bca0c4e59217dce4fa84c7e832 /usr/bin/touch
10 4a5ba7097e0c98a585752c53ac80ef2c4dcbdd6e ima-ng sha1:3f873b5f14641a55eedfd5a715940018b086ae7f /usr/bin/touch
10 1ba8293ea10d2de1deed21174a04e299746639cf ima-ng sha1:a685d70fda356e2008e6b8ae2f8687ec157f494e /usr/bin/xdg-settings
10 ad047340eb4539844e4b044ed780ffd23ad3d7f1 ima-ng sha1:4aa1793bcca0e25797c19f7fef78a9cba48ad02f /usr/bin/xdg-settings
```

Running for example `sha1sum /usr/bin/cat` manually gives me the second recorded hash.

Now, why/how does Linux get different sha1 hashes for the very same file? The files don't seem to be modified at all - modify,change,birth dates (according to `stat`) are well in the past.

Let's assume that there is some reasonable explanation for this behavior (maybe some difference between different opening mechanisms like `mmap` vs something else?), does this mean that I need to be aware of both variants of a file's hash when auditing this list? In other words, do I assume correctly that it would be unsafe to ignore the first of the two entries and just verify the second line for e.g. `/usr/bin/cat`?